# skb->priority and IP::tos and ping -Q

Tags: linux, networking, linux-device-driver

I'm developing some network driver and I'm trying to assign packets to different queues basing on ip::tos value. For testing purposes I'm running:

```
ping -Q 1 10.0.0.2
```

to set ip::tos value to 1. The problem I've got is that on this system where I run ping command - outgoing skb has skb->priority==0, but I think it should be 1.

I assumed that setting "-Q 1" will set skb->priority to 1, but it isn't.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is no direct mapping between the skb->priority and the IP TOS field. It is done like so in the linux kernel:

```
sk->sk_priority = rt_tos2priority(val)
...

static inline char rt_tos2priority(u8 tos)
{
    return ip_tos2prio[IPTOS_TOS(tos)>>1];
}
```

(and the ip_tos2prio table can be found in ipv4/route.c).

It seems to me you'll have to set the "TOS" byte to atleast 32 to get skb->priority to anything other than 0.

ping -Q 1 sets the whole TOS byte to 1. Note that TOS is deprecated in favor of [DSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services_code_point). The 2 low-order bits are used for ECN, while the upper 6 bits are used for the DSCP value (the "priority").

So you likely have to start at 4, to get a DSCP priority of 1, but according to the above table, start at 32 to get skb->priority set as well,  as in `ping -Q 32 10.0.0.2`

However, I'm not sure that will set the skb->priority as well in all cases. If the `ping` tool crafts packets using raw sockets, it might bypass setting the skb->priority.

However, skb->priority for locally generated packets will be set if one does e.g.

```
 int tos = 32; 
 setsockopt(sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS,
                          &tos, sizeof(tos));
```

So you might need to cook up a small sample program that does the above before sending packets.

Comment: When I set -Q 0xff I get skb->priority=4, for -Q8 it is 2 and for -Q0x18 it is 4 again. For -Q4 it is still 0. Strange - maybe  I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @user2699113 That's probably intended. Look in the table I mentioned in ipv4/route.c  + read up on a primer on the different DSCP classes

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is right, Let's complete it here

```
static inline char rt_tos2priority(u8 tos)
{
    return ip_tos2prio[IPTOS_TOS(tos)>>1];
}
```

where IPTOS_TOS is a macro, which ANDs "tos" value with 0x1E

So, If you give TOS as 0xFF, the above return statement reduces to

```
return ip_tos2prio[(0x1E & 0xFF)>>1];
```

calculate it further, (0x1E & 0xFF) is equal to 0x1E,
and (0x1E >> 1) gives us 0x0F, which is 15 in decimal.
we can say that above return statement is equal to

```
return ip_tos2prio[15];
```

Now "ip_tos2prio" is a predefined array, like this

```
const __u8 ip_tos2prio[16]={0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,6,6,6,4,4,4,4};
```

where each distinct value has a meaning, 0->BESTEFFORT, 2->BULK, 4->INTERACTIVE BULK, 6 ->INTERACTIVE.

get back to the return statement, it returns the 15th element in **ip_tos2prio** array, which is 4.